# Error plugin firebase with IONIC 3

Tags: angular, firebase, ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic3

I've been trying to integrate firebase for my ionic 3 project for a while, but every time I add a firebase plugin (I've tried analitycs and with fcm) and try to export the apk I get the following error:

```
>     BUILD FAILED in 1s
>     at ChildProcess.whenDone (D:\myproyects\ionicproyect proyectos\myapp\platforms\android\cordova\node_modules\cordova-common\src\superspawn.js:169:23)
>     at emitTwo (events.js:126:13)
>     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:214:7)
>     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:925:16)
>     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:209:5) (node:1492)
> UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This
> error originated either by throwing inside of an async function
> without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled
> with .catch(). (rejection id: 1) (node:1492) [DEP0018]
> DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In
> the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the
> Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
```

Any ideas? Thanks

Comment: What cordova android version are you on?

Comment: @Misha130 the last version, 8.0.0

Comment: Latest from github is 7.1. Try downgrading to 6.4 since some libraries still dont support latest version

Comment: OK, I'll try and tell you, thank you very much for your response @misha130

Comment: Please shrare some other details of the problem as this information is incomplete..